# Building submodule project using Build defintion

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Am creating new build definition in that am supposed to build dependency project first before building my project, but the dependency project is available in sub module, how to build sub module project from the build definition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the submodule stored as a file with the submodule sha-1 value in the main repo, so you can not select the project in submodule repo by `…` button. But **you can specify the path for submodule project directly**.
Assume your main repo structure as:

```
root
  |___ .git      
  |___ files or subfolders for the main repo
  |___ subRepo
          |___ subproject
                   |___ subproject.sln
```

If you need to build the subproject.sln for submodule (subRepo), you can sepecify the path for solution as: `subRepo/subproject.subproject.sln`

Comment: Thank you for the help @Marina - MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Get Sources" task, click on "Advanced Settings" and make sure "Checkout Submodules" is enabled.

Comment: that option is helping me to check out the sources of submodule, but if i want to build a specific project which is available in submodule, in build definition when am trying to select the project is not showing,

my issue is that before building my project i want to build a project available in submodule is it possible both has to be under same build definition

Comment: @PavanKumar Yes, it's possible, you just need to specify the submodule project directly in the build definition.